# Base class static information contains same for different inherited classes. How to Resolve?

Tags: c#, oop

I store configuration informations in base class for working of the inherited classes:
I have a ControlledMainClassDataInColumns base class what handling everything related SQL based, DataRow stored informations. For its working uses configuration informations in static List variables: specialFieldReferences. This filled by its inherited classes.

```
public class ControlledMainClassDataInColumns : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    public static List<TableFieldReference> tableFieldReferences = new List<TableFieldReference>();

    public Open(Int64 ID)
    {
    //...
    }

    public Save();
    {
    //...
    }
}
```

I have inherited different classes what handling:
Employee table with fields: EmployeeID, FirstName, SecondName, EmployeeDeleted, EmployeeValidFrom, ...
Item teble with fields:     ItemID, ItemName, ProductCode, ItemDeleted, ItemValidFrom, ...
The configuration happening in the Employee and Item classes, during the first instance creation:

```
Class Employee : ControlledMainClassDataInColumns
{
    //...
        public Employee(Int64 employeeID, DateTime validFrom)
        {
            //If the base class static list is not filled, this is filling
            if (specialFieldReferences.Count == 0)
            {
                specialFieldReferences.Add(new FieldReference(fieldType.ClassControllerField, "EmployeeID"));
                specialFieldReferences.Add(new FieldReference(fieldType.ValidityFromField, "EmployeeValidFrom"));
                specialFieldReferences.Add(new FieldReference(fieldType.DeletedField, "EmployeeDeleted"));
            }

            Open(employeeID);    //In the base class, this handles the loading of data
        }
    //...
}
```

Or in the Item class:

```
Class Item : ControlledMainClassDataInColumns
{
    //...
        public Item(Int64 itemID, DateTime validFrom)
        {
            //If the base class static list is not filled, this is filling
            if (specialFieldReferences.Count == 0)
            {
                specialFieldReferences.Add(new FieldReference(fieldType.ClassControllerField, "ItemID");
                specialFieldReferences.Add(new FieldReference(fieldType.ValidityFromField, "ItemValidFrom");
                specialFieldReferences.Add(new FieldReference(fieldType.DeletedField, "ItemDeleted");
            }

            Open(itemID);    //In the base class, this handles the loading of data
        }
    //...
}
```

There are no problem while I'm using only the assignments one of the classes:

```
Employee emp1 = new Employee(1, DateTime.Parse("2018-08-17"));  //First time of Employee, so this fills up specialFieldReferences
//... add some field data
emp1.Save();
// . . .
Employee emp99 = new Employee(99, DateTime.Parse("2018-08-17"));    //99th time, nothing happens about specialFieldReferences
//... add some field data
emp99.Save();
```

But when I start to use the Item class like:

```
Item item1 = new Item(3, DateTime.Parse("2018-08-17"));         //First time of Item, but specialFieldReferences already filled !
```

I run into trouble. During Debug I see that, the specialFieldReferences.Count is already 3 ! It was remained from the Employees class initialisation.
How can I handle that the static variable of the Employee inherited class do not show the same information for Item inherited class?

**Edit - The solution**
So What I did:
Changed this line:

```
public static List<TableFieldReference> tableFieldReferences = new List<TableFieldReference>();
```

to these lines:

```
public string classIdentifier = null;

private static Dictionary<string, List<FieldReference>> _specialFieldReferences = new Dictionary<string, List<FieldReference>>();

protected List<FieldReference> specialFieldReferences
{
    get
    {
        if (_specialFieldReferences.ContainsKey(classIdentifier))
            return _specialFieldReferences[classIdentifier];
        else
            return null;
    }
    set { _specialFieldReferences[classIdentifier] = value; }
}
```

And changed the beginning of the instance:

```
    public Employee(Int64 employeeID, DateTime validFrom)
    {
        //If the base class static list is not filled, this is filling
        if (specialFieldReferences.Count == 0)
```

To:

```
    public Employee(Int64 employeeID, DateTime validFrom)
    {
        classIdentifier = "Employee";

        //If the base class static list is not filled, this is filling
        if (specialFieldReferences == null)
```

And now it is doing well!

Comment: remove `static` from `tableFieldReferences` and make it an instance field.

Comment: You can't. That's what static does. The whole reason for static is to have something that is not limited to an instance. If you want something that is limited to instances, use an instance field. If you want something that is specific to a type, use a type-specific static field. I would say that this is probably a bad pattern however...

Comment: I don't want to run the configure step every time when I create any instance! There are lot of configuration information (not written here), what wastes much time and memory!

Comment: @Jettero then you need to review your current design choice.

Comment: The static exactly what I need: store configuration one time and use for all instance of same inherited class

Comment: [object Object] Please give solution for this.

Comment: We're telling you that using a static field results in the issue you are presenting us with. There is no way of using a static field in a base class and have it work the way you want. Arguing with us about it won't make that fact go away, nor can we offer a solution, since there isn't one. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but that's the reality of the situation.

Comment: If in program I cant do in other way, is there any way to tell to the compiler that make separate code for every inherited class?

Comment: @Jettero - no, that is not possible.

Comment: Please do not include "the solution" as a part of the question. Instead, post it as an answer to your own post.

Comment: Ok. I saw in many question that the finalized solution is also written in the question as Update part, so easy to follow by others... There I didn't see this "answer to your own post" writing - I thought because these are not in the Answer part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must have a static member that you want to add/read data from then the only way to do it in this context is to add a discriminator of some sort. The code that makes use of this data will have to keep this into consideration, you could use an overriden instance field as the descriminator value. In the example below I used a hard coded string but I think you get the picture.

The other recommendation I have is that if you are going to be adding some data once to this static variable per type then use the static constructor, not the instance constructor.

```
public abstract class ControlledMainClassDataInColumns
{
    public static Dictionary<string, List<TableFieldReference>> tableFieldReferences = new Dictionary<string, List<TableFieldReference>>();
}

public class Employee : ControlledMainClassDataInColumns
{
    static Employee()
    {
        var list = new List<TableFieldReference>();
        // populate list
        tableFieldReferences["Employee"] = list;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm happy now. I could not accept that I can't do something logic. I've got also this type of idea: I think I should use also a getter-setter with a not static switch variable in the base class what pointing in this list of static List<TableFieldReference>. Thank you!